# Why are the variables are not taking the desired values

Tags: abap

I have to check how many hundreds are there in a number and translate that number to letters. For example the number 700. I have done the following code:

```
DATA(lv_dmbtr) = ZDS_FG-DMBTR. //Declared local variable of type DMBTR, thus DMBTR=700.

lv_dmbtr = ZDS_FG-DMBTR MOD 100. //Finding how many times 700 is in 100 via MOD and putting the value in lv_dmbtr.

  IF lv_dmbtr LE 9. //The value is less or equal than 9(if larger means that the DMBTR is larger than hundreds, 
                       e.g. 8000)

    lv_hundred = lv_dmbtr / 100. // Divide the 700 with 100, taking the number 7.
    lv_hundred_check = lv_hundred MOD 1. // Then taking the value of 7 into the new variable, done in case the 
                                            lv_hundred is a decimal value, e.g. 7.32.

    IF lv_hundred_check > 0.
     CALL FUNCTION 'SPELL_AMOUNT'
  EXPORTING
    amount    = lv_hundred_check
*   CURRENCY  = ' '
*   FILLER    = ' '
   LANGUAGE  = SY-LANGU
  IMPORTING
    in_words  = lv_hundred_string  // the value is put in the new string
  EXCEPTIONS
    not_found = 1
    too_large = 2
    OTHERS    = 3.
   ENDIF.
```

Now when I debugg the code, all the variables have the value 0. Thus, `lv_dmbtr, lv_hundred,  lv_hundred_check` all have the value 0.

May anyone of you know where the problem may be?

Thank you in advance!

Sorry for writing a lot in the code, just wanted to clarify as much as I could what I had done.

Comment: I am afraid you use the wrong logic here, MOD gives you the reminder (after a division), so 700 MOD 100 = 0, because 700 = 7 * 100. 701 MOD 100 would be 1, because 701 = 7 * 100 + 1

Comment: @JózsefSzikszai I see thank you for the reply, then is there any operations similar to MOD, that would do in case of 700 that there are 7 hundreds?

Comment: simple division? lv_dmbtr = ZDS_FG-DMBTR / 100. lv_dmbtr has to be declared as integer.

Comment: @JózsefSzikszai yes, but in case the value of DMBTR is 8000, is there any if condition I can add so that the division would be only for hundreds values?

Comment: I don't fully get the original problem. Do you want to display (by letters) how many hundreds are in a specific number? So 700 => seven, 1414 => fourteen, etc?

Comment: @JózsefSzikszai lets say that the value of DMBTR is 8000 and not 700, 8000/100 = 80, thus it will read wrong. I wanted to know if there is any way so that it would check firstly the value of DMBTR if is an hundred value and then would continue with the operations.

Comment: @JózsefSzikszai yes so I want to display the value of a specific number 700-> seven, 1400-> four.

Comment: `simple division? lv_dmbtr = ZDS_FG-DMBTR / 100. lv_dmbtr has to be declared as integer` Jozsef already answered you. And check if ZDS_FG-DMBTR structure is not empty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> yes so I want to display the value of a specific number 700-> seven, 1400-> four.

So the basic formula to get the hundred in a number is the following: Find out how many times `100` fits completely into your number with integer division.

```
99 / 100 = 0
700 / 100 = 7
701 / 100 = 7
1400 / 100 = 14
1401 / 100 = 14
```

Now you can simply take this number `MOD 10` to get the the individual hundreds.

```
0 MOD 10 = 0
7 MOD 10 = 7
14 MOD 10 = 4
```

Keep in mind that ABAP, in contrast to many other programming languages, rounds automatically. So in code this would be:

```
CONSTANTS lc_hundred TYPE f VALUE '100.0'.

DATA(lv_number) = 1403.
DATA(lv_hundred_count) = CONV i( floor( ( abs( lv_number ) / lc_hundred ) ) MOD 10 ).
```